# Import Excel file and insert into RavenDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, ravendb

I want to upload an excel file and store every record into RavenDb.

the code like

```
            string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";

            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);

            excelConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I have no idea what I need to do after executereader, anyone can show me the solution??

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any experience using RavenDB?

Here are some pointers:

1. Create a connection with a RavenDB instance. In your case it's probably easiest to use a Embedded instance:

   ```
   var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore{    DataDirectory = "Data"   };
   ```
2. Open a Session on the documentstore
3. Iterate through the objects returned by your query and save those to the repository:

   ```
   session.Store(entity); session.SaveChanges();
   ```

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/Csharp/client-api/basic-operations/understanding-session-object

This should get you on your way.